# openstack: unable to ping and ssh from host network to guest network

Tags: openstack

i have centos 7 linux machine. I have openstack installed on it. In openstack i have installed cirros os image. I am unable to ping and ssh from centos to cirros os image.

Comment: Can you give me some more details about your networking ?? Is it extnet ?

Answer (score 1):

To access the guest machine from the host machine:

**Option-1**: You need to use the `provider network` or `external network` for creating the guest machine.

**Option-2**: If you use `internal network` for the guest machine which is internal to particular openstack tenant/project then you have to create a `floating IP pool` and attach one `floating IP` to that guest instance

Using one of the above options you can access the guest machine from host machine